# Null output for objectId in parse.com ios

Tags: ios, xcode, null, parse-platform, objectid

I am trying to get objectId of babyInfo Class and want to link it to the User class of parse.com. But null objectId is being returned in all of these cases.

```
PFObject *babyInfo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"BabyInfo"];
babyInfo[@"babyname"] = babyname;
babyInfo[@"gender"] = gender;
babyInfo[@"dob"] = date;
  NSLog(@"Object ID: %@", babyInfo.objectId); //First method tried unsuccessfully
    [babyInfo saveInBackground];


  NSString *objectid=[babyInfo objectId];
    NSLog(@"%@",objectid);  // Second method tried unsuccessfully

    NSString *objectid= [babyInfo valueForKey:@"objectId"];
    NSLog(@"%@",objectid);  // Third method tried unsuccessfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are using saveInBackground, so the log statements are logging null as the object hasn't saved yet. Also, your first log statement will definitely log null because it comes before the save statement. Try this:

```
PFObject *babyInfo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"BabyInfo"];
babyInfo[@"babyname"] = babyname;
babyInfo[@"gender"] = gender;
babyInfo[@"dob"] = date;

    [babyInfo save];


  NSString *objectid=[babyInfo objectId];
    NSLog(@"%@",objectid);
```